# E-olymp: Profit. 90% gives, one test wrong answer

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

[image: Here the full exercise]

Description of my code:
For example, take `n = 3`, and let `p [i]` be `1 2 3`. For beginnings, `max = 0`. I take in this order the sequences: `1, 1 + 2, 1 + 2 + 3, 2, 2 + 3, 3` and every time I find the amount of some kind, I compare it with the max amount.

My code is this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//f - number of all sequences(sequence length 1 to n)
//n - number of p[i]
//q is sequence sum
//x this is the number that increases when we get to the last element. For example, the numbers 1 2 3, when we reach 1 + 2 + 3, then x grows and go to 2, 2 + 3
int main()
{
    int n, i, f = 0, q, x = 0, max, j; 
    cin >> n;
    int *p = new int[n]();
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++, f += i) {
        cin >> p[i];
    }
    max = p[0];
    for (i = 0 ; i < f; x++ ) {
        q = 0;
         for (j = x; j < n; j++,i++) {
             q += p[j];
             if (q >= max) {
                 max = q;
             }
         }
    }
    cout <<max;
    return 0;
}
```

And this is 90% result:

[image: And this is 90% result]

Comment: These kinds of tests are designed to check that you have handled _all_ the edge cases.  The failing ones are probably due to special cases, rather than indicating a generally incorrect algorithm.  You'll need to read the specification over and over, until you get an idea of what possible unexpected inputs would be considered valid and test it.

Comment: Please rename your variables so that it's understandable what they are supposed to do. For example, it is not clear the purpose of `f`.

Comment: @kiner_shah f - number of all sequences(sequence length 1 - n)

Comment: @WithOrxan, please update your code and replace all variable names with meaningful names.

Comment: Something for you to consider: what if the maximum profit the cows can make is actually a loss?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the profit may be negative, in this case the algorithm should pick the least bad day, since zero days are not allowed.

Initialize `max` to `INT_MIN`.

Comment: The least possible `int`. C++ equivalent is `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()`, but since this code uses naked `new`, and all variables are on top of the function, C `INT_MIN` suits better here :-)

Answer (score 0):

Every time you entered "P<sub>i</sub>", check if `sum` + P<sub>i</sub> is positive or not. 
If it is not then `sum` = 0 
Else update `sum` to `sum` + P<sub>i</sub> 
Update ans

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

using ll = long long;
using ld = long double;
const int INF = 1e6;

int main()
{
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false); cin.tie(0); cout.tie(0);
    int n; cin>>n;
    int mx = -INF;
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1;i<=n;i++){
        int x; cin>>x;
        if(sum + x > 0){
            sum += x;
        }
        else{
            sum = 0;
        }
        mx = max(mx,sum);
    }
    cout << mx << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This should work